# How to convert string to unix epoch milliseconds without creating local date time objects

Tags: java

My application can receive datetime information in any of below formats :
"yyyymmdd HH:mm:ss.miliseconds"
"yyyymmdd HH:mm:ss.nanoseconds"

Length for Milliseconds && nano second portion can vary from 0-9.

Example :
"20200616 00:00:00.0"
"20200701 02:43:01.47456884"

I am using below code to convert incoming to unix epoc millis :

```
 private static final DateTimeFormatter TIMESTAM_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE).appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendPattern("HH:mm:ss")
            .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
            .toFormatter();
  LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse((CharSequence) input, TIMESTAM_FORMATTER );
                Instant instant = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
                return instant.toEpochMilli();
```

Above code ends up creating a lot of local date-time objects && Instant Object, which i need to avoid in low latency application.

Is there any other way that this string can be parsed without creating LocalDatetIme && instant objects with every call ?

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149563/should-we-avoid-object-creation-in-java Are you sure it's the _creating of objects_ that is slowing your application down?

Comment: I would recommend that you not do anything that reduces the readability of your code unless you're sure you have a problem that your change will actually resolve.  The parsing of the incoming CharSequence is what is costly here, not the fact that that the result of that operation ends up wrapped in a LocalDateTime object.  I'd suggest that you heed famous warning...“Premature optimization is the root of all evil” .

Comment: ...if you decide what you really need is to optimize the parse itself, then I like @ChrisFoley's idea.  This is especially powerful if your dates tend to all be in the last few days, or if they are sequential such that you can cache the date portion of the prior value, much like Chris explains, and then look for that same date in the next value you need to parse.  Lots of tricks to be done, but even there, I'd suggest that you not decide you have a problem without having evidence that a particular one exists.  Prove the problem exists before solving it.

Comment: My answer below was taking the latency problem stated in the question at face value. Of course if you haven't profiled your application then that is the first step.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to cache offsets calculated using local date time for part of your String, and do the simple maths for the rest.

For example, you could cache all values for: yyyymmdd on application startup. This would mean you only have to calculate HH:mm:ss.nanoseconds and add it to the cached version.

Knowing more about your application could inform the decision on whether to cache yyyymmdd HH, or even more. It could also inform what date range you really want to cache (although the year 0 to the year 9999 is under 4 million days).

Caching the portion that I suggest means that you avoid having to think about leap years and varying days of the months. You can also write tests using your original code as an oracle to check for things like leap seconds and other oddities in our calendar.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will try to do this approach

Comment: I would be interested to hear the impact on performance, if you are able to share.